# Posting php results after calculation in form field

Tags: php, forms, post

This form takes in data only in the "inp" field. To multiply two numbers you'd have to input the first number then hit "=" to send the number to the "out" field then type in the second number and hit "*". I am attempting to post the results($result) of calculations into the "out" field and not sure how to do this using php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

php:

```
$input = $_POST['inp'];
$output= $_POST['out'];


if($_POST['submit'] == 'add') {
    $result = $input + $output;
    //set result to "out"
}
else if($_POST['submit'] == 'sub') {
    $result = $input - $output;
    //set result to "out"
}
else if($_POST['submit'] == 'mul') {
    $result = $input * $output;
    //set result to "out"
} 
else if($_POST['submit'] == 'div') {
    $result = $input / $output;
    //set result to "out"
}
else if($_POST['submit'] == 'equ') {
    $result = $input;
    //set result to "out"
}
```

form:

```
<body>
    <form action = "calc.php" method = "post">
        <input type="text" value="0.0" name="out" readonly/>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="inp"/>
        <input type="submit" value="+" name="add"/>
        <input type="submit" value="-" name="sub"/>
        <input type="submit" value="*" name="mul"/>
        <input type="submit" value="/" name="div"/>
        <input type="submit" value="=" name="equ"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: add something like this `<input type="text" value="<?=!empty($result)?$result:"0.0"?>" name="out" readonly/>` instead your `<input type="text" value="0.0" name="out" readonly/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you php and html code in the same file you can write simple write to `out` input value calculated result. Try something like this:

```
<body>
    <form action = "calc.php" method = "post">
        <input type="text" 
             value="<?=!empty($result)?$result:"0.0"?>" name="out" readonly/>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="inp"/>
        <input type="submit" value="+" name="add"/>
        <input type="submit" value="-" name="sub"/>
        <input type="submit" value="*" name="mul"/>
        <input type="submit" value="/" name="div"/>
        <input type="submit" value="=" name="equ"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this works beautifully!! Thank you so much. Also I have an error in my php. The computations should be like this: if($_POST['add']) {
  $result = $output + $input;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code.

```
$result= '';

    if ($_POST) {

        $input = (int) $_POST['inp'];
        $output= (int) $_POST['out'];


        if(isset($_POST['add']) && !empty($input)) {
            $result = $output + $input;
            //set result to "out"
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['sub']) && !empty($input)) {
            $result = $output - $input;
            //set result to "out"
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['mul']) && !empty($input)) {
            $result = $output * $input;
            //set result to "out"
        } 
        else if(isset($_POST['div']) && !empty($input)) {
            $result = $output / $input;
            //set result to "out"
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['equ']) && !empty($input)) {
            $result = $input;
            //set result to "out"
        } else {
            $error = "Please enter a number";
        }
    }
```

```
<body>
<form action="cal.php" method = "post">
    <input type="text" value="<?=!empty($result)?$result:"0.0"?>" name="out" readonly/>
    <input type="text" value="0" name="inp"/>
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="add"/>
    <input type="submit" value="-" name="sub"/>
    <input type="submit" value="*" name="mul"/>
    <input type="submit" value="/" name="div"/>
    <input type="submit" value="=" name="equ"/>
</form>
<p><?=isset($error)?$error:''?></p>
```

Comment: can you please also explain by words what is your solution